# How to update UIViewRepresentable/UIViewControllerRepresentable content properly?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Recently I decided to start studying **SwiftUI** and chose the map app as my starting point. The idea behind the app is to actually show the map, show the user's position, and show multiple overlays that are loaded from several ***geojson*** files. I'm trying to load ***geojson*** files asynchronously and somehow apply them to map. But I can't figure out how one can add an overlay to the map right after the ***geojson*** data is loaded and processed.
`updateUIViewController` gets called too frequently and I only want to add overlays after updating them in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you want to make sure your view is destroyed and recreated as little as possible within `SwiftUI`.

For that, you can indeed benefit from the `updateUIViewController` and `updateUIView` methods in the `Representable` protocols.

They will be called whenever your view, or the enclosing view state changes. So it is important to understand what is triggering that many updates: which `@State` properties are changing? are you modifying a `@Published` property inside an `ObservableObject` multiple times unnecessarily?

For iOS 15, you can use `print(Self._printChanges())` in your enclosing `View`'s `body` to have Xcode to print what caused the `View` to re-render.

All-in-all, having that figured out, you can also opt for simple booleans in order to perform the work just once: that's far from a bad practice, but you need to make sure to get your conditional right!

For instance:

```swift
func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
  guard geojson != nil, !alreadyLoaded else { return }

  // update your view here...
  alreadyLoaded = true
}
```

As mentioned, make sure you revert `alreadyLoaded` to `false` if you need the view to be updated again.